# WebRtc stream without loss of quality

Tags: webrtc, kurento, simplewebrtc, openwebrtc

My web application records video streams on the server side using webRtc and kurento media server. Its just writing the raw stream received from the client to disk. But I was faced with the fact that the quality of the video falls dramatically. All because of codecs and compression. Is it possible to send video without compression at all? The number of FPS is not important to me. 5 FPS for my purpose is pretty enough. The main criterion is 100% quality, or close to it. How to achieve this? Is there any codec that compresses without loss of video quality?
Server side of my app is written in Spring java

[image: recorded video info]

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly your server does here? Does it *recompress* the video sent by the client? What's the quality of the "raw" video sent by the client?

Comment: My server records and saves short videos, 5-10 seconds long.

Comment: Not answering any of my questions really…

Comment: No it's not recompress. My coal is just record video without quality loss. Client side send stream from webcam, or mobile camera.

Comment: So you are just writing the raw stream received from the client to disk? So the client is sending too-heavily compressed video?

Comment: Exactly. I need to send video without compression if its possible, even sacrificing frames per second

Comment: Not sure whether it's possible to set a WebRTC client to prioritise quality over realtime delivery. Let's see if somebody else does…

Comment: It's possible to configure frames per second in constrains. I did it and it sends 5 fps heavy compressed video with bad quality...

Comment: any answers to this?